# Functions on the nonnegative orthant

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, optimization

If $f$ is said to be on the nonnegative orthant, what, exactly, does that mean? Is a function $f: \mathbb{R}_{+}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ considered to be on the nonnegative orthant, or is the codomain restricted to $\mathbb{R}_{+}$?

Comment: Without further context, I would interpret it as "the domain of the function is $\mathbb{R}^n_+$" and not anything more. I would not assume the codomain is $\mathbb{R}_+$ without further explanation.

Comment: And “nonnegative” means $\ge 0$, so your $\mathbb{R}_+$ should contain zero. (Maybe that's what you meant, but it's not clear from the notation.)